# How to vertically align a table and a graphic

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I have a table and a graphic I'd like to vertically align. My current code is:

```
\begin{figure}[tbp]
\CenterFloatBoxes
\begin{floatrow}
\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ |l|c| } 
 \hline
 Barbican & 0 \\  \hline
 Riverside Walk & 1 \\  \hline
Cheapside & 2 \\  \hline
St Paul's & 3 \\  \hline
Moorgate & 4 \\  \hline
Temple \& Whitefriars & 5 \\  \hline
Bank & 6 \\  \hline
Aldgate \& Tower & 7 \\  \hline
Holborn & 8 \\  \hline
Eastern City Cluster & 9 \\  \hline
Guildhall & 10 \\  \hline
Fenchurch \& Monument & 11 \\  \hline
Fleet Street & 12 \\  \hline
Chancery Lane & 13 \\  \hline
West Smithfield & 14 \\  \hline
Liverpool Street & 15 \\ \hline
London West & 16 \\ \hline
London South & 17 \\ \hline
London North & 18 \\ \hline
London East & 19 \\ \hline
External West & 20 \\ \hline
External North & 21 \\ \hline
External south & 22 \\ \hline
External East & 23 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{map1}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
```

However this comes out with:
[image]

I've been trying for nearly an hour now to work out how to align them. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a *full* MWE.

Comment: It depends a bit on what you mean by vertically align. With `\begin{tabular}[b]{ |l|c| }` you can align at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

To achieve this, many ways exist. I suggest using the `adjustbox` package for proper alignment of the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbp]
\begin{tabular}{ |l|c| }
 \hline
 Barbican & 0 \\  \hline
 Riverside Walk & 1 \\  \hline
 Cheapside & 2 \\  \hline
 St Paul's & 3 \\  \hline
 Moorgate & 4 \\  \hline
 Temple \& Whitefriars & 5 \\  \hline
 Bank & 6 \\  \hline
 Aldgate \& Tower & 7 \\  \hline
 Holborn & 8 \\  \hline
 Eastern City Cluster & 9 \\  \hline
 Guildhall & 10 \\  \hline
 Fenchurch \& Monument & 11 \\  \hline
 Fleet Street & 12 \\  \hline
 Chancery Lane & 13 \\  \hline
 West Smithfield & 14 \\  \hline
 Liverpool Street & 15 \\ \hline
 London West & 16 \\ \hline
 London South & 17 \\ \hline
 London North & 18 \\ \hline
 London East & 19 \\ \hline
 External West & 20 \\ \hline
 External North & 21 \\ \hline
 External south & 22 \\ \hline
 External East & 23 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth,height=1.1\linewidth,valign=m]{map1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum (off topic :) ):**

Your image and table are too wide to fit in text width (for example determined by package `article` and also by `\usepackage{geometry}`). You need to make the picture narrower.

To my taste, it is better to have the table on the right side of the image and without any rules:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe,% in real document this option had to be deleted
            margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tbp]
\includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth,height=1.1\linewidth,valign=m]{map1}
%
\begin{tabular}{ r l }
0   &   Barbican            \\
1   &   Riverside Walk      \\
2   &   Cheapside           \\
3   &   St Paul's           \\
    \addlinespace
4   &   Moorgate                \\
5   &   Temple \& Whitefriars   \\
6   &   Bank                    \\
7   &   Aldgate \& Tower        \\
    \addlinespace
8   &   Holborn                 \\
9   &   Eastern City Cluster    \\
10  &   Guildhall               \\
11  &   Fenchurch \& Monument   \\
    \addlinespace
12  &   Fleet Street            \\
13  &   Chancery Lane           \\
14  &   West Smithfield         \\
15  &   Liverpool Street        \\
    \addlinespace
16  &   London West             \\
17  &   London South            \\
18  &   London North            \\
19  &   London East             \\
    \addlinespace
20  &   External West           \\
21  &   External North          \\
22  &   External south          \\
23  &   External East           
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use some specific commands from `floatrow`: `ttabbox` and `ffigbox`. Also `\killfloatstyle`  for captions of different kinds of floats (not necessary here).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, floatrow}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\CenterFloatBoxes
\begin{floatrow}
\hfill
\ttabbox{%
\begin{tabular}{ |l|c| }
 \hline
 Barbican & 0 \\ \hline
 Riverside Walk & 1 \\ \hline
Cheapside & 2 \\ \hline
St Paul's & 3 \\ \hline
Moorgate & 4 \\ \hline
Temple \& Whitefriars & 5 \\ \hline
Bank & 6 \\ \hline
Aldgate \& Tower & 7 \\ \hline
Holborn & 8 \\ \hline
Eastern City Cluster & 9 \\ \hline
Guildhall & 10 \\ \hline
Fenchurch \& Monument & 11 \\ \hline
Fleet Street & 12 \\ \hline
Chancery Lane & 13 \\ \hline
West Smithfield & 14 \\ \hline
Liverpool Street & 15 \\ \hline
London West & 16 \\ \hline
London South & 17 \\ \hline
London North & 18 \\ \hline
London East & 19 \\ \hline
External West & 20 \\ \hline
External North & 21 \\ \hline
External south & 22 \\ \hline
External East & 23 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}}{}
\killfloatstyle
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{map1}}{}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple `[b]` option for the tabular and `booktabs` seems to me a nicer choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}rl@{}}
    \toprule
    0   &  Barbican        \\  
    1   &  Riverside Walk  \\  
    2   &  Cheapside       \\  
    3   &  St Paul's       \\  
    ... &  ..              \\
    23  &  External East   \\  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}\quad
  \includegraphics[scale=.7]{map1.png}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]